# Text only nagios page

Tags: nagios

I was wondering if it is possible to set up nagios to both display its normal page (e.g. critical alerts) in its normal format (red for all alerts on its critical page) and in a basic text format (no colors or graphs, no links to hosts either). What I am looking for is the normal page to display on our wall mounted monitors for all to see, and for a basic text page so that if alerts have to be emailed to certain groups it can be in plain text. Was thinking of creating my own page and stick it in the nagios /html folder but trying that with a test page does not seem to work (page is visible but does not update). Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: NAGIOS already has the facility to email text alerts to people, and it doesn't involve the web interface.  Can you be clearer about what you're trying to do, and possibly why?

Comment: It is possible. You have to parse the `status.dat` file. Plus nagios already has the ability to SMS,etc. Your have to be a bit more clear.

Comment: Essentially I want two different pages with the same output. All the critical alerts but one page should be the normal nagios critical alert page and the other should be a plain text version of that same page. The plain text page should be stripped down to simply the <host>, <alert name>, <alert status> <how long it has been alerting>, and <actual alert>. I know Nagios has the sms ability but the plain text would be more for emailing purposes I do not need the sms alert ability at this time.

Comment: Have you already looked on http://exchange.nagios.org/ to see if there is any plugin/module/add-on that will do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your answers but I think I found what I am looking for from here

http://www.randomwalking.com/snippets/nagios_text_summary.text

While it displays ALL the hosts and their services I can easily parse that out to something manageable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When you say page, do you mean alert, or web page?  You can create separate alert types by creating new commands, then selecting the command as host_notification_commands or service_notification_commands in the configs for the hosts and services.  So you would create a different notification, that sends the data you want in the format you want, and use that in your service or host definitions.

If you are talking a separate web page, an html page and a text page, I'm not sure if that is possible, but it could be researched more.  So far I'm not seeing anything about that, although I am finding a lot of pages for prettying up alerts.

Comment: No I mean web page, I too did the research first before coming here. But as you say I only found pages about making the alerts more presentable. I will keep looking but thank you for your help.

Comment: Just for curiousity what happens if you turn off images on the browser?  That would be all text.

Comment: It still is in html with tables and such, though.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for.  I haven't tested it, though: `https://github.com/shiziwen/nagios-status2txt/blob/master/status-txt.c`

Answer (score 0):

The [Thruk](http://www.thruk.org/) add-on for Nagios allows export to JSON for a lot of its pages, including the "problem hosts" and "problem services" page.  I swear it used to do CSV, but I can't get my thruk install to do anything other than JSON and XLS at the moment.

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but if you end up writing something yourself, it should be something you can make use of to make your scriptwriting a little easier.